# Maximum area bounded by a rod of fixed length and string of fixed length

Tags: geometry, analysis, convex-optimization

A string of length $p$ is fixed at two ends of a straight rod AB of length $L$. What should be the shape of the string to enclose a region of maximum area with the rod and the string as the boundary of the region?

Given $p > L$.

Looks like the string needs to be wound in form of a circular arc. Is it right? Any rigorous proof?

Comment: Dido's problem.

Comment: Not exactly @Cesareo. In Dido's problem, the rod is of infinitely large. This is a variation of Dido's.

Comment: A circular arc is a solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation. I haven't an elementary solution at the moment.

Comment: I am having trouble to set the double constraints, length of the rod is $L$ and the length of the string is $p$ in Euler-Lagrange equation. @Aretino, could you please help by giving your solution?

Comment: Because the rod is of fixed length, the semicircular arc is not optimal.  Consider a rod of length 1 inch and a string of length 10 feet.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: Not a semi-circular arc, but a circular arc of chord-length $L$ and perimeter $p$. For example, if  $p=2L$, the arc subtends an angle more than $pi$ at the center. But I am looking for a proof using variational calculus.

Comment: This question was answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402686/proof-a-special-extension-on-the-isoperimetric-theorem

Comment: @Aretino, Thanks.